# Export to Excel with server side webapi and list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, export-to-excel

I am getting the response from API on a generic list 
 `IEnumerable<myClass> objClass`.

Here I am trying to export the list to a CSV file using StreamWriter

```
var serviceResponse = await services.GetProfileRepositoryAsync(requestDto, token);
                if(requestDto.IsExportable)
                {
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    **writer.Write((serviceResponse.dto.NewSoftwareFileDto));**
                    writer.Flush();
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    return File(stream, "text/csv", "filesname.csv");
                }
```

Since `serviceResponse.dto.NewSoftwareFileDto` returns a list the `writer.Write` is not wring the content. Once I have used Objectresult with `writer.Write()` method and it was working earlier. Now I am not able to recollect it.

**I want to avoid looping through the list and writing data.**

Comment: u r in a wrong way. u can only write string or binary data to response.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a DTO list directly to a `MemoryStream` using `StreamWriter.Write()`, because [`StreamWriter.Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) only accepts either `char`, `char[]` or `string` as first parameter. Since you want to avoid using loops (either `for` or `foreach`), you could use LINQ to create a `List<string>` from existing list of DTO as comma-separated values and then write its contents into the stream:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

// create list of strings from DTO list
List<string> items = serviceResponse.dto.NewSoftwareFileDto.Select(x => 
      string.Join(",", x.Property1, x.Property2, ...)).ToList();

// insert newline between every lines (i.e. list indexes)
string combined = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);

// write combined strings to StreamWriter
writer.Write(combined);

writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
return File(stream, "text/csv", "filesname.csv");
```

Note that `Property1`, `Property2` etc. represents property names inside list of DTO object, depending on order of definition. The property names used in `Select` must be available inside `NewSoftwareFileDto`.

Comment: In my case the properties are dynamic, that means the properties can vary

Comment: Are the property names dynamic (i.e. isn't known until runtime)? If that's the case, you may try using `IDictionary` cast: `var items = serviceResponse.dto.NewSoftwareFileDto.Select((IDictionary<string, object> x) => string.Join(",", x["Property1"], x["Property2"], ...)).ToList()`, or cast it to a DTO class.

Comment: I have modified using Linq , there i am missing the header (ie column names

Comment: Can you describe "missing column name/header"? Are they not exist inside CSV file, or you want to include headers? What is the actual type of `serviceResponse.dto.NewSoftwareFileDto` in runtime? The `IDictionary` cast only used if your DTO model is not known until runtime, and indexer with property name as string like `x["Property1"]` used instead of directly calling property name like `x.Property1`.